# How to set TLS cipher for Go server?

Tags: ssl, encryption, go

I'm currently using the following listen and serve command to run a secure websocket/file server:

`http.ListenAndServeTLS(":443", "site.crt","site.key", router)`

However, I want to set the cipher to TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 and also set a min SSL/TLS version.

How can I do this?

I think I need to use this [Config](https://golang.org/src/crypto/tls/common.go?s=8340:12616#L233) structure somehow, but I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

2015: You can see an example in [`secrpc/tls_server.go`](https://github.com/rollbackup/secrpc/blob/d39882fcd2a6cd32ad6874725084f256e35251ec/tls_server.go):

```
tls.Listen("tcp", addr, &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    CipherSuites: []uint16{
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
        tls.TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256,
    },
    MinVersion:               tls.VersionTLS12,
    PreferServerCipherSuites: true,
})
```

See also [go/issues/11047](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/11047) for an example using ListenAndServeTLS: once you have defined your `Config`, you define your server:

```
server := &http.Server{Addr: ":4000", Handler: nil, TLSConfig: config}
server.L
```

---

In 2021, you also have "[Automatic cipher suite ordering in crypto/tls](https://go.dev/blog/tls-cipher-suites)" from [Filippo Valsorda](https://twitter.com/FiloSottile):

> [Go 1.17](https://go.dev/doc/go1.17#crypto/tls), recently released, takes over cipher suite preference ordering for all Go users.
>
> While `Config.CipherSuites` still controls which TLS 1.0–1.2 cipher suites are enabled, it is not used for ordering, and `Config.PreferServerCipherSuites` is now ignored.
>
> Instead, `crypto/tls` [makes all ordering decisions](https://go.dev/cl/314609), based on the available cipher suites, the local hardware, and the inferred remote hardware capabilities.